# Multiple posts in one page

Tags: posts, customization

lately I see more and more sites with this feature.
In single post page you can read other posts too and the url changes at page scrolling (like this [one](https://www.digitalic.it/internet/web/comportamento-utenti-navigazione) ).
Do you mind how it is possible? is there a plugin?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is called **infinite post scrolling with URL change**. The demo you linked to is using AJAX to accomplish that. I have never used infinite post scrolling before - so I can't tell if the website you linked to wrote their own code or used a plugin.

But since you asked specifically for a plugin: those are available. :)

Search the [Wordpress.org plugin directory](https://wordpress.org/plugins) with these four keywords "[**infinite post scrolling url**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/infinite+post+scrolling+url/)" and that will help you narrow down the list of available plugins. You can then test them and choose what suits you best.